# Re-formatting Date object (Java)

Tags: java, date, calendar, date-format

I am currently working on a basic RSS Feed program that displays tweets given a parse-able Twitter source. What I'm currently working on is re-formatting the date. When I retrieve the pubDate it parses in the form "EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z." What I want to do is re-format it such that when I display it on my GUI, it comes out as "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm." How do I go about doing this? Here is the necessary chunk of code:

```
try {
    builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document feedDocument = builder.parse(sourceListItem);
    XPathFactory xpfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
    XPath xpath = xpfactory.newXPath();
    String countStr = xpath.evaluate("count(/rss/channel/item)", feedDocument);
    int itemCount = Integer.parseInt(countStr);
    for(j=1; j<=itemCount; j++) {
        try {
            String title = xpath.evaluate("/rss/channel/item[" + j + "]/title", feedDocument);
            String link = xpath.evaluate("/rss/channel/item[" + j + "]/link", feedDocument);
            String date = xpath.evaluate("/rss/channel/item[" + j + "]/pubDate", feedDocument);
            DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z");
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            Date d = df.parse(date);
            DateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm");
            String dateFormat = df2.format(d);
            c.setTime(d);
            RSSItemClass rssItem = new RSSItemClass(title, link, c);
            rssList.add(rssItem);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            badSourceList.add(sourceListItem);
        }
    }
} catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
    badSourceList.add(sourceListItem);
}
```

Comment: Where's the question/problem? It looks like you have a solution already although you're not using the formatted date string `dateFormat`.

Comment: My `Date d` parses the form "EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z" but when I display the date in my GUI, I don't want it coming out in that format, I want it to come out in the format "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm." Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you seem to "display" the value of a `Calendar` object in your GUI, you don't have to format the date in the method you posted but only when the date is converted to a string in the GUI.

How this is done depends on the GUI framework you're using but most likely you need this code somewhere:

```
DateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm");
String formattedDate = df2.format(calendar.getTime());
```

Where  `calendar` is the `c` you pass to `new RSSItemClass(title, link, c);`

Answer (score 0):

You have the line `String dateFormat = df2.format(d);` in your code but you don't use the `dateFormat` variable anywhere.

Comment: When I try to parse the String `dateFormat`, I'm not getting my desired "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm" format.

Comment: @michal-kosmulski The parameters are correct. `SimpleDateFormat` is a `DateFormat` which has a `format(Date)` method.

Comment: Also, that `format()` method that takes three params is for SimpleDateFormat and I'm using DateFormat.

Comment: @Mike why would you parse `dateFormat` again? It should be the already formatted string you want.

Comment: @Thomas I need to put that string into my `Calendar c` which at the moment is set to `Date d`

Comment: Calendar works with Dates, DateFormat parses and formats Dates by provided format. What is your GUI? Which property does GUI display?

Comment: The GUI is displaying type Calendar

Comment: @Mike well then add some conversion from calendar to string into your GUI's display code.

Comment: My instructions are that once the date is parsed, I must change the format and store it into an RSSItem so that when I display the RSSItem in my GUI it will display the correctly formatted date.

Comment: @Mike note that if you store calendar and not the formatted string inside the `RSSItem` you'll have a problem since calendars and dates are just unformatted time information (there is no notion of formatted time at all, it's just the conversion from a timestamp to a string where the formatting is necessary).

Comment: @Mike You're right, I missed the `format(Date)` method in docs.